# using switch case for loading pages in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I learned Codeigniter basics but i then stopped. So im relearning.

I know there are more advanced ways of doing this but i'd like to do things my way in which i can understand. I don't want to bite off advanced stuff that will only confuse me. Copy pasting snippets online is very easy but i want to understand everything in my code.

Anyways, i've always used if statements back in php, idk why, i never really looked up proper guidelines in coding so in some cases where a switch case was best i was still using the familiar if statements.

So in my project, my links are made this way.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>pages/view/home">Homepage</a>
```

And in my controller, i have set up my view method to take out the uri-segment to know which pages to load.

```
$data = array('page' => $this->uri->segment(3,home));

switch ($data['page']){
case 'home';
$data['tile'] = "Homepage";
$data['page'] = "userhome";
break;
case 'login';
$data['tile'] = "Login";
$data['page'] = "userlogin";
break
}

$this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
$this->load->view('templates/navbar');
$this->load->view('pages/'.$data['page']);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

But it doesn't work. The title and page won't change.

I can easily do this with if else statement.

```
$temp = $this->uri->segment(3,'home');

if($temp == "home"){
$data = array('title' => 'Homepage' , 'page' => 'home');
$this->load->view('template/header',$data);
$this->load->view('template/navbar');
$this->load->view('pages/'.$data['page']);
$this->load->view('template/footer');
}else if($temp == "login"){
$data = array('title' => 'Login' , 'page' => 'userlogin');
$this->load->view('template/header',$data);
$this->load->view('template/navbar');
$this->load->view('pages/'.$data['page']);
$this->load->view('template/footer');   
}
```

I read somewhere that switch case is faster than an if else, i'm just showing you the first 2 pages ive made so far, login and homepage but any other pages ill make in the future will be loaded in the same way so the code will get longer. that's why i was interested in using switch case.

This worked though

```
$temp = $this->uri->segment(3,'home');      
        switch ($temp){
        case 'home':
        $data = array('title' => "Homepager" , 'page' => "home");
        $this->load->view('template/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('template/navbar');
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$data['page']);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');   
        break;
        case 'login':
        $data = array('title' => "Login" , 'page' => "userlogin");
        $this->load->view('template/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('template/navbar');
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$data['page']);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');   
        break;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think it's the best way to use if / switch for this. CodeIgniter has his own router, use it and write 1 function by page. And for your problem, `var_dump` your `$data['page']` variable to see if it contains good value.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you have a mistype in the `switch` statement, you're assigning values to `data['tile']`, instead of `data['title']` ?

Comment: Furthermore, in the **if** example the page is "home" but in the **switch** example the page is "userHome".

Comment: My problem was that it didnt change the values.

I don't know if the switch case code ran.

Comment: I changed those names here, theyre irrelevant. i got lazy to change them back here thats why those differences. check the edit, i added my new switch case that did work.

Comment: How lazy were you when you posted the view method code using switch because there are two errors...

Comment: which block? the first or the second one? The second one works fine for me.

Comment: The first one - the one that doesn't work for you and the reason you are here posting this question.